# Implementing SAML SSO for Canvas Apps - Need help

Tags: single-sign-on, canvas, saml

I am trying to implement SAML SSO for Canvas Apps. I have followed all steps stated in the article "Implementing SAML SSO for Canvas Apps"

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Implementing_SAML_SSO_for_Canvas_Apps

I keep seeing the following error in the console when I hit 'Refresh SR' button

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://sp-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://sp-dev-ed--c.na16.visual.force.com')

How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance.